# Python Nested JSON Import - Convert to table

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to import a json file (in this case from a FB profile export) that has a number of nested levels. In Excel I'm able to create a query that converts all the data into a table in about one minute (expanding nested levels to new columns eight or nine times).

In python though, using either the json functions or the pandas reading functions, it's seeming to be an impossible task. Pages like https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas# are helpful to partially flatten the json, but that only works with one target level. To convert a number of different nested levels into a single table seems to require multiple flattening efforts each customized to the file in question.

I thought the whole point of json was to make such stuff easier though, right? So when I can do something in Excel in about 10 clicks and I can't find a way to do it in python without deep customization work I can't help but wonder if I'm missing something. Is there no easy way to convert a multi-level nested json automatically to a table in python? Or at least with less effort? I've got a whole stack of jsons to import and at this rate I'd be better off using Excel to create csv files from them than trying to fit python imports to each one. What am I missing?

Comment: Please add a sample of the file you are trying to parse

Comment: I would love to and wanted to on the original, but unfortunately there's almost not a single piece of the file that's not private data. I'm in the process of trying to generalize this or replace all the private pieces to be able to share but it's taking time. :-/

I'd hoped the above was general enough to communicate the problem without a sample needed. The point is, there should be a generic way to do this in python regardless of the number of nested levels, right? Also, the link included has samples that are similar, if not nested so deep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def flatten_json(org_json,sep='_'):
    flattened = {}

    def flatten_level(d, prefix=''):
        if type(d) is dict:
            for k in d:
                flatten_level(d[k], prefix + k + sep)
        elif type(d) is list:
            for i,k in enumerate(d):
                flatten_level(k, prefix + str(i) + sep)
        else:
            flattened[prefix[:-1]] = d

    flatten_level(org_json)
    return flattened
```

Comment: This seems to flatten rows into variables instead of columns. The result is not a table with all the data available, as in the excel version, but a massive number of variables.